# Search issues with non-alphanumerical characters when using PHP and SQL db

Tags: php, sql, regex, pdo

I'm having trouble figuring out how to implement a search on an SQL db when parts with non-alphanumerical characters are searched.

The search works great except when there is a character such as a hyphen, or parentheses in the part number being searched. (Some part numbers have forward slashes, but those are returned properly when queried.)

For example: A search for 1492-PDL3111 returns 0 results.
(Partial string searches work well, so if I search for 1492 I will get the 1492-PDL3111 part number returned along with 1492-PDL31124, 1492-PDL3141, 1492-PDL3161, which is great, but if I include the hyphen, I'm back to 0 results. I also get correct results when I do a partial string search from the middle or end of a string. The only failure is when I do a search for a part number which has non-numerical characters.

I'm pasting the code below with the hope someone here can assist. I've searched and searched for a solution to no avail.

Thanks in advance!
Thymallus

```
<?php 
$searchcross=$_GET[ 'crossref']; 
$remove=array( " ", "-"); 
$searchcross=str_replace($remove, "", $searchcross); 
if ($searchcross !="" ){ 
$query=$handler->prepare("SELECT * FROM php_cross_reference WHERE competitor_part_no LIKE :part_no ORDER BY competitor_part_no;"); 


$query->bindValue(':part_no', '%' . $searchcross . '%');   
$query->execute(); 
if ($query->rowCount()){ ?>

<!--If statement, only make this if there are results?-->
<div class="table-section">
  <table class="search-table search-table-alt">
    <caption>
      <?php echo 'Search results for "'. $searchcross . '"' ?>
    </caption>
    <tr>
      <th>Competitor Part Number</th>
      <th>Competitor</th>
      <th>Our Part Number</th>
    </tr>

    <!--This is where the PHP loop should begin-->
    <?php 
      while ($r=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 
    ?>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <?php 
          echo '<strong>',$r[ 'competitor_part_no'], '</strong>' 
        ?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php 
          if ($r[ 'competitor_name']){ 
            echo $r[ 'competitor_name']; 
          } else { 
            echo 'N/A'; 
          } 
        ?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php 
          if ($r[ 'product_documentation']){ 
            echo '<strong><a href="',$r[ 'product_documentation'], '">',$r[ 'our_part_no'], '</a></strong>'; 
          } else { 
            echo '<strong>',$r[ 'our_part_no'], '</strong>'; 
          } ;?>
      </td>

      <?php 
        } 
        //PHP loop end 
      ?>
  </table>
</div>

<!--  PHP if statement end?-->
<?php 
    } else { 
      echo '<h3 class="module">Your search returned '.$query->rowCount().' results.</h3>'; 
    } 
  } else { 
    echo '<h3 class="module">please enter a search</h3>'; 
  } 
?>
```

Comment: because you remove the hyphen and any spaces here -> $remove=array( " ", "-"); 
$searchcross=str_replace($remove, "", $searchcross);

Answer (score 0):

You're removing hyphens and spaces from the search string when you do:

```
$searchcross=str_replace($remove, "", $searchcross);
```

If you want to ignore these characters when searching, you also need to remove them from the strings in the table. So the condition in the query should be:

```
WHERE REPLACE(REPLACE(competitor_part_no, '-', ''), ' ', '') LIKE :part_no
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input. The spaces and hyphens were actually being removed from this array:
$remove=array( " ", "-");
That's not what was desired and once I looked at their code again, I saw the issue.
I removed that line of code and it works perfectly.